# Testing linked function in angular directive doesn't work

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, angularjs-directive, jasmine

I'm quite new to the unit-testing using jasmine and karma. I'm trying to test the function that's in the link in the directive. It's being called on the click event that I'm trying to get. Note that I'm using jQuery for jasmine and html templates are from my.templates module. It selects the right  element and clicks it but it doesn't start the scope.callback function and it's never called.

Directive.js

```
(function() {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('MyModule')
        .directive('dropdownFilter', function() {
            return {
                restrict: 'E',
                require: '^ngModel',
                scope: {
                    ngModel: '=', // selection
                    items: '=',   // items to select from
                    callback: '&' // callback
                },
                link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
                    element.on('click', function(event) {
                        event.preventDefault();
                    });

                    scope.default = 'Select';
                    scope.isButton = 'isButton' in attrs;

                    // selection changed handler
                    scope.select = function(item) {
                        scope.ngModel = item;
                        if (scope.callback) {
                            scope.callback({ item: item });
                        }
                    };
                },
                templateUrl: 'app/dropdown/dropdown.html'
            };
        });
})();
```

Dropdown.html

```
<div class="btn-group" uib-dropdown>
    <button ng-if="isButton"
            type="button"
            class="btn btn-primary"
            ng-bind="ngModel.label || default">
    </button>
    <button ng-if="isButton"
            type="button"
            class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle"
            uib-dropdown-toggle>
        <span class="caret"></span>
    </button>

    <a ng-if="!isButton"
       class="dropdown-toggle"
       uib-dropdown-toggle href
       ng-bind="ngModel.label || default">
    </a>
    <span ng-if="!isButton" class="caret"></span>

    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
        <li ng-repeat="item in items">
            <a href="#"
               ng-bind="item.label"
               ng-click="select(item)">
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Tests

```
describe('documents dropdown directive', function () {
    var scope, $rootScope;

    beforeEach(angular.mock.module('MyModule'));
    beforeEach(angular.mock.module('my.templates'));

    beforeEach(inject(function ($rootScope, $compile) {
        scope = $rootScope.$new();
        scope.myItem = {};
        scope.items = [
            {id: 2, label: '132'},
            {id: 3, label: '131'},
            {id: 4, label: '123'}
        ];
        compile = $compile;
    }));

    it('should render simple directive', function() {
        var element = compile("<dropdown-filter ng-model='myItem' items='items'></dropdown-filter>")(scope);
        scope.$digest();

        expect(element.html()).toBeDefined();
    });

    it('should call callback function when its there', function() {
        scope.callback = function(){};
        var element = compile("<dropdown-filter ng-model='myItem' items='items'></dropdown-filter>")(scope);
        scope.$digest();

        spyOn(scope, 'callback');

        var button = $j(element).find('ul').find('a').first();
        button.click();

        scope.$digest();
        expect(scope.callback).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
});
```